# Как перманентно удалить элемент html из кода?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5, вёрстка

Как с помощью js или jQuery удалить элемент html кода так, чтобы при перезагрузке страницы он не появился опять?

Comment: сохраните данные о куске в localstorage. при загрузке страницы читайте оттуда данные и удаляйте

Comment: Извините, а это как?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=localstorage

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div id="to-delete">useless text</div>
```

```js
localStorage.setItem("Id of el to delete", "#to-delete")

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
   cosnt id = localStorage.getItem("Id of el to delete")
   const elToDelete = document.querySelector(`#${id}`)
   elToDelete.remove()
})
```